# Toast Notification after Submit in Angular (Success or Failed)

Tags: angular, http, toast

I'm a beginner with Angular, so excuse me if it will be very easy for you.
I would like to print a Toast Notification after the action 'submit' from the user, green if success (in other page), red if failed (in the page with the form).
Currently, I save the data in a db and navigate to the view of the post, my api returns code 200.
I thought to pass the status code of http, or a boolean variable, but i don't know how pass to another page/component. Here is what I have tried

```
if (this.actionType === 'Add') {
        const post: Post = {
        /....../
          data: this.form.get(this.formData).value
        /....../
        };
        this.postService.savePost(post)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/post', data.id]);
          });
      }
```

This is my function in Service

```
savePost(post): Observable<Post> {
    return this.http.post<Post>(this.myAppUrl + this.myPost, JSON.stringify(post), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      );
  }
```

Thanks so much

Comment: create a shared  message service and a msg component and use it : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/07/05/angular-8-alert-toaster-notifications

Comment: this.postService.savePost(post)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/post', data.id]);
            // print success message here
          },
          error => // print error message here);

You can use any of 3rd party libs like https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api or whatever to show your toast.

Comment: @AntonLee Its possible print html in your solution?

Comment: do you need toast or show message inside of your page?
Write down new component, for example MessageComponent, and pass msg string and type of message (success, error, info) inside, and show it when error or success occurs.

Comment: I need a 'alert' that say 'Post added successfully' after the redirect to the view of post, or 'Posting Failed Post' after the submit in the page with form if there is some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code work using ngx-toast.

```
this.postService.savePost(post)
              .subscribe(
               data => {
                this.router.navigate(['/post', data.id]);
              this.showSuccess();
              },
              error => ( this.showError(); )
          );
    showSuccess() {
        this.toastr.success('Post Added', 'Success');
      }
    showError() {
        this.toastr.success('Something went wrong', 'Error');
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the npm package (ngx-toastr) for toast notification - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr/v/8.8.0